# Casos de teste java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, testes

Estou tentando realizar um teste no sistema bancário que eu fiz, estou utilizando o netbeans para isso.

Preciso que realize teste na opção sacar e depositar, no caso o que eu fiz até agora só da erro em tudo, mais não entendi porque não digitei nada para realizar o teste, alguém sabe como fazer? e se puder me explicar.

Class Caixa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Caixa {


public static void main(String[] args){
    // Declarando as variáveis, Scanner e Random
    String nome;
    double inicial;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random numero = new Random();
    int conta = 1 + numero.nextInt(9999);

    //Obtendo os dados iniciais do Cliente
    System.out.println("Cadastrando novo cliente.");
    System.out.print("Ente com seu nome: ");
    nome = entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Entre com o valor inicial depositado na conta: ");
    inicial = entrada.nextDouble();
    if(inicial <= 0){
       System.out.println("Não é possível iniciar com esse valor!\n");
    }
    else
    {

    //Criando a conta de um cliente
    Conta minhaConta = new Conta(nome, conta, inicial);
    minhaConta.iniciar();
}

}
}
```

Class Conta:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conta {
private String nome;
private int conta, saques;
private double saldo;
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

public Conta(String nome, int conta, double saldo_inicial){
    this.nome=nome;
    this.conta=conta;
    saldo=saldo_inicial;
    saques=0;
}

public void extrato(){
    System.out.println("\tEXTRATO");
    System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
    System.out.println("Número da conta: " + this.conta);
    System.out.printf("Saldo atual: %.2f\n",this.saldo);
    System.out.println("Saques realizados hoje: " + this.saques + "\n");

}

public void sacar(double valor){
if(valor <= 0){
  System.out.println("Não é possível sacar esse valor!\n");
}
else
{
  if(saldo >= valor){
      saldo -= valor;
      saques++;
      System.out.println("Sacado: " + valor);
      System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
  } else {
      System.out.println("Saldo insuficiente. Faça um depósito\n");
  }
}
}

public void depositar(double valor)
{
if(valor <= 0){
  System.out.println("Não é possível depositar esse valor!\n");
}
else
{
  saldo += valor;
  System.out.println("Depositado: " + valor);
  System.out.println("Novo saldo: " + saldo + "\n");
}
}

public void iniciar(){
    int opcao;

    do{
        exibeMenu();
        opcao = entrada.nextInt();
        escolheOpcao(opcao);
    }while(opcao!=4);
}

public void exibeMenu(){

    System.out.println("\t Escolha a opção desejada");
    System.out.println("1 - Consultar Extrato");
    System.out.println("2 - Sacar");
    System.out.println("3 - Depositar");
    System.out.println("4 - Sair\n");
    System.out.print("Opção: ");

}

public void escolheOpcao(int opcao){
    double valor;

    switch( opcao ){
        case 1:    
                extrato();
                break;
        case 2: 
                if(saques<3){
                    System.out.print("Quanto deseja sacar: ");
                    valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                    sacar(valor);
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Limite de saques diários atingidos.\n");
                }
                break;

        case 3:
                System.out.print("Quanto deseja depositar: ");
                valor = entrada.nextDouble();
                depositar(valor);
                break;

        case 4: 
                System.out.println("Sistema encerrado.");
                break;

        default:
                System.out.println("Opção inválida");
    }
}
}
```

E aqui e a Class ContaTest que faz os teste, aqui está o problema ou na verdade algo que eu não consegui fazer:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;


/**
 *
 * @author aluno
 */
public class ContaTest {

public ContaTest() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@Test
public void testSacar() {
    System.out.println("sacar");
    double valor = 0.0;
    Conta instance = null;
    instance.sacar(valor);
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}


@Test
public void testDepositar() {
    System.out.println("depositar");
    double valor = 0.0;
    Conta instance = null;
    instance.depositar(valor);
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que clico em testar aparece isso :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que `Conta instance = null;` deve causar `NullPointerException`. Se vc postar o erro, fica mais fácil de ajudar. Tente criar mais um construtor nas classes sem parâmetros de entrada, aí vc pode fazer: `Conta instance = new Conta();`

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo editei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Conta instance = null;
>
> instance.sacar(valor); /* ou instance.depositar(valor); */
> ```

Você não citou qual é a falha do teste então não tem como ser 100% assertivo, mas com certeza isso resultará em `NullPointerException` e seus testes irão falhar.

Faça algo como `Conta instance = new Conta(nome, conta, saldoInicial);` e então execute o saque ou depósito. Ex:

```
@Test
public void testSacar() {
    System.out.println("sacar");
    double valor = 0.0;
    Conta instance = new Conta("Joao", 1, 1000.0);
    instance.sacar(valor);
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

Comment: Coloquei as imagens na pergunta de como faço... eu queria que realizasse os teste, tipo eu digitar o nome e o saldo inicial, depois fazer as opções e tals

Comment: @Ferb na imagem da pra ver o console dizendo que é `NullPointerException`. Faça uma instância de `Conta` com `new Conta(nome, conta, saldoInicial)` e provavelmente irá funcionar (ou pelo menos não dará `NullPointerException`)

Comment: A onde eu irei fazer isso no meu código ?

Comment: Nos métodos de testes. Ao invés de fazer `Conta instance = null`.

Comment: @Ferb editei a pergunta

Comment: Está aparecendo um ponto de exclamação vermelho agora, falando cannot find symbol e os nomes das variaveis

Comment: @Ferb claro... Até coloquei no final da pergunta para você alterar esses valores para valores corretos...

Comment: @Ferb editei a pergunta... Tente novamente